# insertRowsAtIndexPaths Not Working, Crashing With Object At Index Out Of Bounds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Searched and searched.. can't find an answer :|

I'm pretty sure I'm using insertRowsAtIndexPaths right... Here's my code, along with the error I'm receiving...

First, I receive a response back from the server with comments that I want to insert dynamically into an empty section within my static uitableviewcontroller's tableview.

This is what happens when we receive the response from the server...

[image]

I count the number of comments returned, and generate an array of index paths for the empty section, which is section 1.

I then run the standard way of inserting rows with encapsulation between begin/end updates.

Great..

Now, here's my tableview's related code.

[image]

Everything runs fine once I get the response from the server, insert I assume works...

However, when I start scrolling down the view, as soon as I scroll right before where the first comment would show, I get a crash with the following error, and nothing pointing me in any direction as to what it could be

[image]

It's the strangest thing... and from my NSLog right before the crash I can see it's attempting to get cell for index path of section 1 row 0, which would be where the first comment SHOULD be... What's going on??

**UPDATE**
Here is the value of self.recentComments prior to the indexPaths array being created.

[image]

**UPDATE 2**
Here's the value of self.recentComments in the cellForRowAtIndexPath RIGHT before the crash.

[image]

Comment: Incidentally what is the value of `STATUS_OK`?

Comment: Where you are initialization your cell? i can only see dequeue method ? no initialization?

Comment: your array seems to be empty. and you are trying to access the 1st object of an empty array. Hence, the crash.

Comment: In `loadRecentComments` method can you put a break point next to `self.recentComments` and check if the array has any values ? and in future please copy paste the code.

Comment: Status OK is just a constant value of 200 to make sure the request went through successfully. 

This is a static table, the is being dequeued through a registered nib containing a tableViewCell

Comment: GoodSp33d, check the update I just made to the post.

Comment: what about value of self.recentComments in the method cellForRowAtIndexPath? could you post that too please?

Comment: Also, try using exception break points. You will get the exact location of the crash.

Comment: Just updated with value of self.recentComments in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: After checking with the exception break points, it's crashing on here: cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"comment"];

So I tried this, cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init], and still got the same crash at the same place... Does not make any sense

Comment: You have to do a nil check after using `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"comment"];`. i.e `if(cell == nil){cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56167/discussion-between-gogreen-and-braydon-batungbacal).

Answer (score 1):

This is actually very strange. What i would suggest is you just do `[self.tableView reloadData]` instead to `insertRowsAtIndexPath`.

You do this once you get the response from the server :

```
-(void)loadRecentCommentsResponse:(NSDictionary *)data
{
   int status = [[[data objectForKey:@"meta"] onjectForKey:@"status"] intValue];
   if(status == STATUS_OK){
      self.recentComments = [[data objectForKey:@"response"] objectForKeys:@"comments"];
      [self.tableView reloadData];
   }
}
```

SInce you are not reloading the `UITableView` it is unable to recognize the number of row to be displayed in the `numberOfRowsInSection` method.

**Update :**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    //Do your stuff here

   return cell;
}
```

You missed the `if(!cell)` block. It is used so that if the cell is not initialized, it is initialized. Whenever you scroll the `UITableView` this `cellForRowAtIndexPath method is called everytime.

Thanks.

Comment: That's not the issue, the cell is dequeueing from a nib. It crashes as soon as cell is set to any value, my reuse cell, or even a bare uitableviewcell I freshly alloc/init

Comment: can you please tell me what value are you assigning to the cell?? Are you using the cell.textLabel?

Comment: I saw the updated screenshot you have given. Where have you used the self.recentComments array to assign value to the cell??